# How to get songs from a particular artist?

Tags: java, android, mediastore

I'm trying to get songs from a particular artist and i don't how i would do this. The artist will change depending on user input, so it shouldn't be hard coded. Currently, i'm using a `MediaStore` to query all the songs from a device, but i don't know how i would make it so that it only gets songs from the selected artist.

Here's the code...

```
public void displayArtistSongs(String artistName) {
    //retrieve song info
    ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri =  MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, artistName, null, null);

    if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
        //get columns
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        //add songs to list
        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);

            songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, null, null, null));

        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    musicCursor.close();
}
```

I tried passing the `artistName`, as well as previously passing the `artistId` as selections in the cursor, but it still doesn't work. Any solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query all the songs from a selected artist you can use this code:

```
String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST + "=?";
String[] selectionArgs = {artistName};

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, selection, selectionArgs, null);
```